# воспроизведение аудио на сайте по клику без ссылки

Tags: аудио

Каким тегом можно воспользоваться, чтобы аудио воспроизводилось прямо на сайте по клику на значок воспроизведения? как здесь: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-russian/dictionary
`<a href>`  воспроизводит в отдельном окне, `<audio>`, использованный отдельно, просто вставляет плеер, `<img>` колонки с `<audio>` внутри вообще никак не отображается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
znachok.onclick = function(){audio.play()};
let audio = new Audio("sound.mp3");
```

```html
<img id=znachok src="image.jpg" />
```

Правда, по приведенной Вами в качестве примера ссылке используется не элемент аудио, а window.speechsynthesis() для проговаривания текста.

Comment: Странно, когда отправляю ответ со смартфона, js-код не подсвечивается, т. е., выглядит, как обычный текст, а html-код не отображается вообще и исчезают переносы строк, вернее превращаются в пробелы ...

Comment: Эникейщик, а что Вы сделали, что в результате код стал подсвечиваться?

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё заработало! Но только для одного значка... А если у меня 20 и более значков на странице?  Я думала, что хватит замены znachok на znachok2 с одной и той же картинкой, но нет( Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно вставить дополнительные значки со звуком?

Comment: если Вы мне и про подсветку Вашего ответа, я ничего не делала.

Comment: если про мой -<code>&lt;img&gt;</code>

Comment: Нужно уточнить, звук должен быть разным при нажатии на разные значки или одним и тем же?

Comment: Звук должен быть разным, значок выглядит одинаково для всех элементов, но встречается на странице многократно. Примерно так: слово - озвучка, слово - озвучка, слово - озвучка... около 20-30 элементов на странице.

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае нужен speechSynthesis() а не аудио.

```css
<style>
body{column-count: 3}
img{cursor: pointer}
</style>
```

```html
<body></body>
<script>
let data = 
   ["filename1.mp3", "filename2.mp3, filename3.mp3, ... , filenameN.mp3], // имена аудиофайлов
   ["первое предложение", "второе предложение", "третье предложение", ... , "энное предложение"] // предложения
]
let audio = new Audio();
for(i = 0; i < data.length; i ++){
let znachok = document.createElement("img");
znachok.src = "image.jpg";
let mydiv = document.createElement("div");
mydiv.id = data[0][i];
mydiv.name = data[1][i];
mydiv.appendChild(znachok);
mydiv.innerHTML += " " + mydiv.name;
document.body.appendChild(mydiv);
mydiv.onclick = function(){
  audio.src = mydiv.id;
  audio.play();
}    
</script>
```

В этом примере озвучиваются 12 слов, но Вы можете увеличить их количество, просто увеличив длину массива. Пока работает только с английскими словами.

Comment: Нет, извините,  не вариант( я упростила. Это не отдельные слова, а предложения, которые озвучили реальные люди, мне важно, чтобы звучали именно они. И они на немецком. Пожалуйста, если знаете ещё варианты, напишите

Comment: Тогда  пришлось задействовать элемент аудио. Я переделал ответ, теперь в массиве нужно прописать реальные имена аудиофайлов и тексты соответствующих предложений. По нажатию на значки озвучиваются целые предложения. Или должны озвучиваться  слова по отдельности?